# NixOS nVidia Driver Version Bounds

Tags: version, driver, nvidia, nixos

I'm trying to get NixOS to work with my old GeForce 6600, which only accepts an nVidia driver version <305 (304.xx). Is there any way to put an upper bound on the kernel module version / proprietary version in my `configuration.nix`? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `nvidiaLegacy304` instead of `nvidia` in the `system.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia..." ];` declaration (use `hardware.opengl.videoDrivers` for the unstable channel).